# Python - replace list element with string

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I got an assignment where I have a tuple that I should convert to a list, replace the second element and revert back to a tuple. The problem I think I have is that the element is an int and should be replaced with a string. From what I can find here on the interweb I can't really work out a way to do this. Could you perhaps give me some pointers?

```
tupX = ("moose", 12, 1.98, "table", 7)
listX = list(tupX)

listX = [e.replace(1, "elevator")for e in listX]
tupY = tuple(listX

print(tupY)
```

The error message I get is `TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not int`.

Any pointers on this?
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set new value by index:

```
tupX = ("moose", 12, 1.98, "table", 7)
listX = list(tupX)
listX[1] = 'elevator'
tupY = tuple(listX)
print(tupY)
```